# python cocos2d change tile's image

Tags: python, tile, tmx, tiled, cocos2d-python

-I'm using python and cocos2D

I have the file loading a tmx-map but now I want to change a specific tile to display an image from another file, I have saved the specific tile that I want to change in a variable but changing it I don't know how.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was
cell.tile.image = image